# Javascript alert() function ambiguity

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the background color of **html body** before displaying an alert message. This is my code:

```
var guess;
  var count=1;
  var color=["red","green","blue","yellow","indigo","purple","black","cyan","violet"];
  var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  alert("I am thinking of "+color[num]+" color");
  function do_game()
  {
    do {
      guess=get();
      if(color.indexOf(guess.toLowerCase())==-1)
      {
        alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color");
        continue;
      }
      if(guess.toLowerCase()>color[num])
      {
        alert("Your color is alphabetically higher than my color!");
        count++;
        continue;
      }
      if(guess.toLowerCase()<color[num])
      {
        alert("Your color is alphabetically lower than my color!");
        count++;
        continue;
      }
    } while (guess.toLowerCase()!=color[num]);
    document.body.style.background=color[num];
    alert("Congratulations! You guessed the color!\n\nIt took you "+count+" guesses\n\nYou can see the color in the background");
  }
```

Here, the background color changes only after I close the alert, even though I've written the code to change color before the alert. Really confused.
**I am using Safari browser**

Comment: Try a zero millisecond setTimeout.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your problem ? I tried to reproduce your problem, but it seemed to work on my end.

Comment: I am using safari. I'll check on other browser

Comment: yea in safari alert message comes first later color changes, in google chrome it works fine.

Comment: you need to put `document.body.style.background=color[num];`  before alert() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
document.body.style.background=color[num];
```

before

```
alert("I am thinking of "+color[num]+" color");
```

and use jquery. Works for me on: safari, chrome, ie 11 and firefox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var guess;
    var count=1;
    var color=["red","green","blue","yellow","indigo","purple","black","cyan","violet"];
    var num=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    document.body.style.background=color[num];
    alert("I am thinking of "+color[num]+" color");
    function do_game()
    {
    do {
      guess=get();
      if(color.indexOf(guess.toLowerCase())==-1)
      {
        alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color");
        continue;
      }
      if(guess.toLowerCase()>color[num])
      {
        alert("Your color is alphabetically higher than my color!");
        count++;
        continue;
      }
      if(guess.toLowerCase()<color[num])
      {
        alert("Your color is alphabetically lower than my color!");
        count++;
        continue;
      }
    } while (guess.toLowerCase()!=color[num]);
    document.body.style.background=color[num];
    alert("Congratulations! You guessed the color!\n\nIt took you "+count+" guesses\n\nYou can see the color in the background");
    }
})
```